# RNN classifier, how to show the weight to understand how the neraul network make the decision

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am using a RNN to build a simple classifier to classify a paragraph of words into different catalogs. it has an embedding layer, followed by RNN and then a Dense layer show as below.

It can predict correctly but besides the prediction, how can I know why the RNN got this prediction, for example, what is the weight on each words of the paragraph.

What words have made the RNN believe it belongs to a specific catalog?

```
model = Sequential()

embedding_size = 300

model.add(Embedding(input_dim=num_words+1, output_dim=embedding_size, input_length=max_tokens, name='layer_embedding', weights=embedding_matrix],trainable=True))

return_sequences=True))

model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(32,return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(32,return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(32)))
model.add(Dense(numdense, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 1):

[This post on GitHub](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3088) proposes a way to see the parameters' name while printing them:

```
for e in zip(model.layers[0].trainable_weights, model.layers[0].get_weights()):
   print('Param %s:\n%s' % (e[0],e[1]))
```

Comment: thanks very much! learn a good way to get weights.  what I want to achieve is to visualize how the model predict specific result, for example, if I give it a paragraph of word, then the model return me a category, which is right, but why, what words in that paragraph make it get the prediction? it might happened during the predict process, right? I hope I can visualize it by add color to those words that the model weight higher.